# Improve arched arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, arrows, tikz-path, arrow-curve

Can you see the curved arrow? Is there any way to make it more elegant? Right now the arrowhead covers part of the curvilinear section. One idea would be to insert two short horizontal strokes before and after the curve.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        N/.style = {minimum height=3ex, minimum width=4.8ex, text depth=0.25ex,inner ysep=6pt},
        shorten <>/.style = {shorten > = #1, shorten <=#1}
                        ]
        \node (cold_in)     [N, right] at (5,0) {$T_{C,L}$};
        \node (cold_out)    [N,  left] at (0,0) {$T_0$};

        \draw[gray, shorten <>=3mm] (cold_out.north east) -- (cold_in.north west);
        \draw[red,  shorten <>=3mm] (cold_out.south east) -- (cold_in.south west);
        \draw[-Straight Barb,dotted] (cold_in) -- (cold_out);
    
        \node (hot_in)     [N,left,anchor=north] at (cold_out.south) {$T_{0}$};
        \node (hot_out)    [N,right,anchor=north] at (cold_in.south) {$T_{L}$};
        \draw[-Straight Barb,dotted] (hot_in) -- (hot_out);
        
        \draw[gray, shorten <>=3mm] (hot_in.south east) -- (hot_out.south west);

        
        \draw[-Straight Barb,dotted] (cold_out.west) to[out=180,in=180] (hot_in.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `looseness=` to your options:

```
\draw[-Straight Barb,dotted, looseness=2] (cold_out.west) to[out=180,in=180] (hot_in.west);
```

Whole numbers are not required, e.g., you can try `1.8` (tighter) or `2.25` (looser). You might also want to consider `densely dotted` instead of `dotted`.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The arrow you have chosen is not very good-looking on tightly curved lines. Your idea is easy to apply, adding straight terms to the line:

```latex
\draw[-Straight Barb,dotted] (cold_out.west) -- ++(-0.1,0) coordinate(tmp) to[out=180,in=180] (tmp|-hot_in.west) -- (hot_in.west);
```

[image]

Another option is to change the arrow and add the `bending` library

```latex
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
...
\draw[-{Triangle[length=2mm,bend]},dotted] (cold_out.west) to[out=180,in=180] (hot_in.west);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Change your line of code

```
\draw[-Straight Barb,-stealth,dotted,shorten >=-5pt] (cold_out.west) to[out=180,in=180] (hot_in.west);
```

with this one:

```
\draw[-latex,dotted,line width=1pt] (cold_out.west) arc (90:270:.4);
```

the output will be:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

using "shorten" with negative value and changing the arrowhead can work.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
    \begin{document}
        
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                N/.style = {minimum height=3ex, minimum width=4.8ex, text depth=0.25ex,inner ysep=6pt},
                shorten <>/.style = {shorten > = #1, shorten <=#1}
                ]
                \node (cold_in)     [N, right] at (5,0) {$T_{C,L}$};
                \node (cold_out)    [N,  left] at (0,0) {$T_0$};
                
                \draw[gray, shorten <>=3mm] (cold_out.north east) -- (cold_in.north west);
                \draw[red,  shorten <>=3mm] (cold_out.south east) -- (cold_in.south west);
                \draw[-Straight Barb,-stealth,dotted] (cold_in) -- (cold_out);
                
                \node (hot_in)     [N,left,anchor=north] at (cold_out.south) {$T_{0}$};
                \node (hot_out)    [N,right,anchor=north] at (cold_in.south) {$T_{L}$};
                \draw[-Straight Barb,-stealth,dotted] (hot_in) -- (hot_out);
                
                \draw[gray, shorten <>=3mm] (hot_in.south east) -- (hot_out.south west);
                
                
                \draw[-Straight Barb,-stealth,dotted,shorten >=-5pt] (cold_out.west) to[out=180,in=180] (hot_in.west);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]